# Redirect console output to null in Windows CE batch file

Tags: batch-file, windows-ce, console-redirect

Tricky thing

this works as expected under windows

```
ping localhost > nul
```

and redirects the output into nirvana.

But i am writing a batch script on a Windows CE 6.0 Device and the same call creates a file "nul". Is it possible to dismiss the console output in CE?

**Update**

This is the output after running `dir * > nul` twice in an empty directory

```
Directory of \flashdisk\test

06/13/13  15:35                      0 nul

Found 1 file(s). Total size 0 bytes.
1 Dir(s) 150664192 bytes free
```

Comment: Are you sure you used the same name in Win CE? Your description of the problem show a name with a couple "L" letters: `null`.

Comment: Sorry, that was just a mistake while writing this question. I verified that the same batch file does not create a file if run on Windows 7 and creates a file on Windows CE

Comment: A workaround would be to use > nul and then delete the nul file.

Comment: @foxidrive - that would work, but I want to minimize writes on the CF Card. Anyway I figured out a better solution myself (see the answer)

Comment: If Win CE is based around Win9x then a pipe is creating a file too.  I'm just musing here though - don't know Win CE.

Comment: Windows CE (>= 4.0) is not at all based on 9x. In case you care, check out wikipedia for an overview on CE's history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution both works on Windows (7) and Windows CE
Just pipe the output to REM

```
ping localhost | REM
```

Comment: Nice one. ;) BTW: /temp writes to a RAM disk, not CF (at least under my setup here).